# psql: error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Davinci"

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, psql, pgadmin

Im trying to setup postgres database for my django project, so i donwnloaded the installer together with the pgadmin. i set a default password when installing and i used it to login to the pgadmin and it worked, i now wanted to run so cli commmand, so i added postgres to path in my system enviroment variable in other to be able to run it on the cli and it works, i mean the system recognise the commands but im getting errors which i think its comming from the database itself. i have no idea about this error, this is my first time using it.
PS: it asked for my system user password and i entered it, then i got the error bellow.

> C:\Users\Davinci>psql

> Password for user Davinci:

> psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Davinci"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `psql -U postgres` and then inserting the password you chose at pgadmin.

User `postgres` is the default, but it seems like Windows is trying to run `psql -U Davinci` when you type only `psql`, so you have to specify which user (`-U` for user / `postgres` for the username) when trying to connect.